# Calling Rails controller data through JS AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, api

I'm making a rails app using this code in the controller to call an API- I initially call the `inventories endpoint`, then make separate calls to two other id endpoints `store_id, product_id` to grabs specifics pieces of data linked to the inventories. This data gets passed into a hash that becomes '@inventories / transformed results':

```
class InventoriesController < ApplicationController
 def index
 response = Typhoeus.get("http://lcboapi.com/inventories")
 parsed_json = JSON.parse(response.body)

transformed_results = []

parsed_json["result"].each do |inventory|
  transformed_results.push(
    {
      product_name: product_lookup(inventory["product_id"]),
      store_name: store_lookup(inventory["store_id"]),
      quantity: inventory["quantity"],
    }
  )
end

@inventories = transformed_results
end
  private

  def store_lookup(store_id)
  response = Typhoeus.get("http://lcboapi.com/stores/#{store_id}")
    parsed_json = JSON.parse(response.body)
  return parsed_json["result"]["name"]
end

 def product_lookup(product_id)
 response = Typhoeus.get("http://lcboapi.com/products/#{product_id}")
     parsed_json = JSON.parse(response.body)
 return parsed_json["result"]["name"]
 end
end
```

My question is how best to get my json hash through AJAX into a form I can pass through and iterate in assets/javascript.

I am aware I can build it into the view (html.erb) and have done so, but I want to make my data interact with DOM elements.

Note: I've tried doing a simple console log to show the json data in the console as a test, with no response. I'm okay with using jQuery until I get comfortable with React, but **I'm not sure how to grab my @inventories data from 'assets/javascript/inventories.js' - for instance, if I wanted to grab something from a csv data bases I'd use the following, but in this case it's not quite there:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  console.log("ready!");
  $.ajax({
url: "/inventories",
method: "GET"
 }).done(function(data){
    var products = []
    data.forEach(function(item){
      products.push(item.product_name).toString();
      console.log(products);
    });
  });

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of your js files (in `assets/javascript`), you'll need to do something like:

```
storeLookupResults = $.ajax({
  url: "/inventories.js",
  type: 'GET'
})
storeLookupResults.success (data) =>
  # do stuff with your results
  # 'data' will contain your json
```

NOTE: I made up the route, so you'll need to make sure you use a real route

Then, in your `InventoriesController`, modify `index` to something like:

```
def index
  response = Typhoeus.get("http://lcboapi.com/inventories")
  parsed_json = JSON.parse(response.body).with_indifferent_access

  @inventories = parsed_json[:result].map do |inventory|
    {
      product_name: product_lookup(inventory[:product_id]),
      store_name: store_lookup(inventory[:store_id]),
      quantity: inventory[:quantity],
    }
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json {render json: @inventories, status: :ok}
  end  

end
```

Note that `.map` returns an `array`. So, you don't have to do:

```
transformed_results = []

parsed_json["result"].each do |inventory|
  transformed_results.push(
    {
      product_name: product_lookup(inventory["product_id"]),
      store_name: store_lookup(inventory["store_id"]),
      quantity: inventory["quantity"],
    }
  )
end    

@inventories = transformed_results
```

Also note that I did:

```
parsed_json = JSON.parse(response.body).with_indifferent_access
```

It's a purely stylistic preference. I like using symbols instead of strings.

Comment: Okay, but that;s are private method to pass in related data from different endpoints. Would I not be able to get my `transformed_results` hash through ajax?

Comment: Aside from rendering the full html script (rather than json) in the ajax call, that works!